# Retrieve item value from DWORD_PTR in combobox?

Tags: combobox, mfc

I want to Retrieve the item value(string) s
where is `s` is

```
DWORD_PTR s = m_laybox.GetItemData(idx);
```

Basically, `s` is selected item and I am saving in config
now how can I get item value(string) from s

Comment: You need to show us the code where you cally m_laybox.SetItemData(). We need to know what type of data is stored as the item data.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are multiple strategies.  One thing you must know is that the data must exist (more or less) for the lifetime of the combobox.  You don't have to put strings in the combobox.  You can, but you can also put object pointers into the combobox (as the item data).

One way I like to do things is to have an array of items and then store an index into the combo box.

But, consider that you put "strings" into the combo box....

You do something like:

say pString is a TCHAR* (or char* or wchar_t*)

```
// for all the items you need to add ....
int idx = m_combo.AddString(pString); // or something different
m_combo.SetItemDataPtr(idx, pString);
```

Afterword, in response to a CBN_SELENDOK or CBN_SELCHANGE, you want to get the data...

You will be given an idx ....

```
TCHAR* pRetrieved = reinterpret_cast<TCHAR*>(m_combo.GetItemDataPtr(idx);
```

CComboBox::GetItemDataPtr() returns an LPVOID. You need to cast that to the type you want.

For a diff example, consider this record...

```
struct ClientInfo
{
   CString m_Name;
   int m_CliendID;
   CString m_Address;
};
```

Consider that maybe you have an array of these records:

```
CArray<ClientInfo> m_arrayClientInfo;
```

Somewhere later you initialize it. Then you want to fill the combo box during a dialog.  You do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_arrayClientInfo.GetCount(); ++i)
{
   int idx = m_combo.AddString(m_arrayClientInfo[i].m_Name);
   m_combo.SetItemDataPtr(idx, i); // store index, not pointer, but you could store pointer
}
```

Sometime later in the program when you want to get the data ...

```
int nArrayIndex = reinterpret_cast<int>(m_combo.GetItemDataPtr(idx));
const ClientInfo& clientInfo = m_arrayClientInfo[nArrayIndex];
```

Those are the basics...don't guarantee anything compiles or works...but it's close